# Regular Expression Notation

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions so I am wondering how to represent a String like 
"hello from the other side - Error(cannot find file)"
using regular expression to group things together. My goal is to only select the words "hello from the other side" and disregard everything after that. I tried hardcoding it but it seems that there can be a random number of whitespaces after "other side" so I don't really know how to select everything after the phrase without specifying the number of whitespaces. 
Please help!

Clarification: the first part can be random but the fixed part is some number of whitespaces followed by - Error .....

Comment: You'll have to be more precise. If you just want to match 'hello from the other side', you can use exactly that as the RE. If you want to match an arbitrary phrase up to and excluding the '-' and all the white space before it, that also is trivial, but you need to clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: We have no idea what you're asking. Would you like the string `foo bar hello from the other side - Error(cannot find file)` to match? If so, what part? What about `hello - Warning(x)`? What can change and still match? Give us some test cases.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear! Just updated a clarification

Comment: So you want to match of all the whitespaces in the following string? `foo bar            - bing`

Comment: @Kevin Yes! Or rather I was to match 'foo bar' and disregard everything after that. How do I account for the space?

Answer (score 2):

There are three groups (I can see) in your input, `x - y(z)` - I would compile a `Pattern` and use a `Matcher`; something like

```
String str = "hello from the other side - Error(cannot find file)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\s+-\\s+(.+)\\((.+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Part 1: %s Part 2: %s Part 3: %s%n", 
            m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3));
}
```

Which outputs

```
Part 1: hello from the other side Part 2: Error Part 3: cannot find file
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, if I am reading this correctly. it seems that the pattern assumes that there is only one space before and after the dash line. However, the number of spaces before the dash line can change.

Comment: @Luming You are assuming incorrectly. This can handle differences in # of spaces around the dash. However, it does assume there is no spacing between `y` and `(z)`.

Comment: Got it! I hope this is not asking too much of you but is it possible to simply group `- y(z)` in one group and the whole `x` in the other?

Comment: @Luming I wouldn't worry about that... all you seem to want is `m.group(1)` (so ignore the second and third ones). The `Pattern` is correct (but yes that is possible - for example, `"(.+)\\s+-\\s+(.+)"`).

Comment: But with this way, if there is multiple spaces before `-`, group(1) would include those spaces. My goal is to neglect all the spaces after `hello ... other side`

Comment: @Luming Again, no. It already does this. Please try it first.

Comment: Yep I did try! Here is what I wrote: 'String str = "hello from the other side    - Error(cannot find file)";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\s+-\\s+(.+)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  if (m.find()) {
      str = m.group(1);
      System.out.println(str);
  }`

Comment: @Luming And that outputs `hello from the other side` here. The `\\s+` matches one or more white space characters, and the white spaces are outside the grouping `()` symbols in the pattern.

Comment: I see the logic... But unfortunately it's giving me 'hello from the other side     ' when I run the code. The string length is 28 rather than 25.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(.*?)\s*\s-\s\w+\(\w*\)/
```

or

```
([^\n\r\u2028\u2029]*?) * - \w+\([^\n\r\u2028\u2029]*\)
```

retrieve your match from group #1

## things that will not match:

```
- Error(x)
hello-Error(x)
hello - (x)
hello - Error
```

## things that will match

```
 - x() #is the minimum needed to trigger a match - though group #1 will be empty
```

```
hello from the other side - Error(cannot find file) #group 1: `hello from the other side`
hello - noarg()                                     #group 1: `hello`
hello from           - Error()                      #group 1: `hello from`
hello    from        - Error()                      #group 1: `hello    from`
```

---

You can use tools like [regex101](https://regex101.com/), [regexr](http://regexr.com/), and regexbuddy to help debug and test regular expressions.